# Windows 7 HDD -> SSD

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-7, hdd, ssd

Два года назад установил SSD. Но переустановку Windows сделал коряво. Проблема возникла при смене метки системного тома. Устанавливал образ с диска, при этом форматнул диск С(где был старый виндовс), попробовал сменить системный том на новый, дальше все перестало работать, после восстанавливал диск С. Дальше я все-таки установил винду на SSD(выделил синим на скрине), но при этом появился новый том(выделил зеленым на скрине), с которым я не знаю что делать. Сейчас хочу установить 10 винду, как правильно поступить в данной ситуации?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Рекомендую для лучшего описания приложить скрин с карты "Управления дисками". Из вопроса не понятно: хотите иметь двойную загрузку, либо установить WIn10 с обновлением Win7 или взамен.

Comment: Сохрани важные файлы на внешний винт, потом снеси из огнемёта все разделы на всех винтах, а потом сделай красиво. Это - единственный короткий путь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из Acronics все настроил, сменил системные и удалил ненужные томы, все работает.